# Enable HTTPS on WCF rest webservice

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-6, wcf-binding, wcf-rest

Enable HTTPS on WCF rest webservice

I've already tried multiple configuration but i'm not able to get my WCF rest webservice working via HTTPS. I get 500 internal errors, or 400 bad request.

I've added a new website into IIS, binded to port 80 and 443. Then, enabled http/https protocols.

Here's my Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
   <service name="RestService.MyService">
     <endpoint address="https://mywebsite.com"
       binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IMyService" />
   </service>
 </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.5" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"/>
  </startup>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="C:\logs\TracingAndLogging-service.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
        name="xml" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following binding configuration to the endpoint.

```
<services>
  <service name="WcfServiceFile.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceFile.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="beh" bindingConfiguration="myBinding">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding >
    <binding name="myBinding" >
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

Don’t forget to apply the bindingconfiguration to the endpoint so that it could take effect.
Result.
[image]
Due to the Self-signed certificate, the connection is not secure.
Feel free to contact me if the problem still exists.